# After successful build at the comand line I get Eclipse error JVM terminated. Exit code=1

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am using eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
Build id: 20210312-0638

I am using it on lubuntu 20.10 64bit.

I have also installed java11 as part of trying to resolve the issue:
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.10, mixed mode, sharing)

The eclipse GUI works just fine and I am able to compile my code. I am interested to compile the eclipse project via the command line(So I can run it as part of a CI pipeline).

When I compile it via the command line my build is successful and I get a binary. the problem is I am getting "JVM terminated. Exit code=1" which make my pipeline to fail.

This is the command I use to compile

```
./eclipse -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors  -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import /<path_to_project>/ -data /<eclipse_work_space> -build <project_name>/Debug
```

This is the full error message I get once compiling is done:

```
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/drone/eclipse/cpp-2021-03/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-launcher /home/drone/eclipse/cpp-2021-03/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/drone/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541/eclipse_11301.so
-startup /home/drone/eclipse/cpp-2021-03/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 20
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild
-import /home/drone/azure_agent/_work/1/s/projects/RT-Linux/
-data /var/tmp/ee
-build linux_sim/Debug
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/drone/eclipse/cpp-2021-03/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
```

This is the eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
/home/drone/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-showsplash
/home/drone/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

I did a search before posting but found no mention of this issue when compiling via the command line.

Edit:
I will be perfectly fine with a way to suppress this error(so my pipeline won't fail because of it) if it won;t suppress compilation errors during the build.

Comment: Anything different if you don't `--launcher.suppressErrors`?

Comment: Not really, I just get the same error but as a popup and not as part of the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue, so for posterity I will explain my specific issue but mostly I strive  to provide a more general explanation of what may be the cause of “JVM terminated. Exit code=1” when using eclipse in heedless mode via the CLI. This is one of possible reasons(most threads dealing with this error attribute it to insufficient memory values, set at the eclipse.ini file).

The root of all evil is the way eclipse communicates errors. In the best case eclipse will  abort the build and state explicitly what had happened(and thanks to David Vavra from the eclipse forum for the examples):

```
Project: file:<whatever> can't be found!
 Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
 Saving workspace.
 Eclipse:
 JVM terminated. Exit code=1
```

```
Workspace already in use!
 Eclipse:
 JVM terminated. Exit code=1
```

And in the worst case, not only eclipse doesn't state what went wrong it will state that everything was just fine. In my case eclipse sent to the stdout:

```
Finished building target: linux_sim
 
15:20:20 Build Finished. 0 errors, 11 warnings. (took 9m:18s.202ms)

Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
```

So in my specific case I have a Debug build and a Release build as part of my eclipse project . I use a toolchain for cross compilation  and all of my builds are compiled with the Debug settings while Release is left unmaintained. A long time a go I have moved from toolchain X to Y but didn't updated the “path” and "prefix" for the Release settings and removed the deprecated toolchain from my machine. This work just fine when I use the GUI.

Once I used eclipse in a heedless mode I explicitly stated that I would like to compile with Debug settings only by stating **-build <project_name>/Debug** and eclipse did compile only the Debug settings.

from the command line:

```
15:11:02 **** Build of configuration Debug for project linux_sim ****
```

There is no mention of:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project linux_sim ****
```

for project linux_sim anywhere during my build.

Although I explicitly stated that I want to compile only the Debug configuration and  although eclipse complied with my request it did try to load the settings for Release and when scrolling all the way to the start of the build process I noticed this two lines:

```
Unable to find full path for "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
Unable to find full path for "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++"
```

Once I cleaned the Release configuration from the “prefix” and “path” of the deprecated toolcahain *“JVM terminated. Exit code=1”** issue was gone.

The real beauty of this issue (besides eclipse loading settings it should not have loaded)is that although **"Unable to find full path for "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc""** qualified as a reason to send to the stdout a **“JVM terminated. Exit code=1”** message eclipse didn't abort the build process and allowed it to finish with a “success” message and only then sent the  “JVM terminated. Exit code=1” message to the stdout without providing any reason as to why.